# Mysql Rollup on daily basis

Tags: mysql

I have a following data Set

```
month | spend
Jan   | 100
Jan   | 200
Feb   | 10
Feb   | 500
Feb   | 100
March | 60
```

I want a rollup on monthly basis like:-

```
Jan  | 300
Feb  | 910 // Spend till month of feb
March| 970 // Spend till month of March and so on...
```

I want Sum month wise with previous month value, i hope you understand.

Comment: You will need some criterion to order the months by in the way you need them so that the query can see which month is the previous month. Do you have any data column which can do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (month text, spend int);
insert into t values 
("Jan",  100),
("Jan",  200),
("Feb",   10),
("Feb",  500),
("Feb",  100),
("March", 60);

select month, (@n:=@n + sum) sum 
    from 
      (select month, sum(spend) sum 
           from t 
         group by month 
         order by FIELD(MONTH,'Jan','Feb','March')
      ) t1 
    cross join 
     (select @n:=0) n
```

Answer (score 0):

If your actual month names are understood by MySQL (check e.g. [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)) you could also use [`STR_TO_DATE('%b', month)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to determine the order of months. Then

```
SELECT t1.month, SUM(t2.spend)
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON STR_TO_DATE('%b', t2.month) <= STR_TO_DATE('%b', t1.month)
GROUP BY t1.month
```